# C#: Sort a list of an array

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, linq

How can I sort the following list by the first column of its elements?
The elements are of type `string[]`.

```
List<string[]> list = new List<string[]>();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This may helps

```
list.OrderBy(input=>input[columnIndex])
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`Enumerable.OrderBy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.orderby.aspx) method with the column index;

> Sorts the elements of a sequence in ascending order.

```
string[] i = new string[] { "one", "two", "three" };
string[] j = new string[] { "four", "five", "six" };

List<string[]> list = new List<string[]>() {i, j};
var newlist = list.OrderBy(n => n[1]);
```

This returns a new sorted list.